# error.php(433)_

Tags: logs

We are seeing the following error every day or so on the log viewer:

plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(433)

How do I go about investigating the possible causes? and significance of "433"

Any help appreciated

Comment: 433 is the line number in the file but what do you mean by log viewer? If you mean https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer then you can click on the log entry to see more info.

Comment: Thank you. I do mean that extension and have now clicked on the entry for more information.

Comment: Thanks again, I am now working through the information and making some sense of it.